# How to restart a CountDownTimer

Tags: android, button, countdowntimer

With android studio I've an app with a countdowntimer. It starts from 10 seconds to 0 when I press a button and a textview that count how many clicks i do on a button,so far so good. I want to restart this all times i want by pressing another button.
Can you help me?
If it helps I put the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like that:

```
static CountDownTimer timer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    [...]

    btnCount.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // start timer once when button first click
            if (!timerStarts[0]) {
                startCounting(10000);
                [...]
            }

            [...]
        }
    });

    btnRestart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //RESTART
            stopCounting();
            startCounting(10000);
        }
    });
}

private void startCounting(long totalTime) {
    timer = new CountDownTimer(totalTime, 1) {
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            [...]
        }

        public void onFinish() {
            [...]
        }
    };
    timer.start();
}

private void stopCounting() {
    timer.cancel();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. Can you just write the entire code? (i mean without points)